# What does it imply when an estimate is not inside its 95% confidence interval?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, mathematical-statistics, data-mining

What does it actually imply when a 95% CI does not contain an estimate (coefficient or parameter). Is there some model assumption that has not been satisfied? Or it means something else?

I know when comparing two group means, if the 95% CI does not contain 0, we can conclude that two group means may be different (since m1 - m2 = 0 is not inside the 95% CI). However, I don't know how to explain why an estimated slope or intercept is not inside its 95% CI.

Could it be that the estimated slope differs from the its mean too much?

Comment: Can you give us a specific example?

Comment: It's not logically contradictory for a CI not to contain an estimated value: the estimate is supposed to be "close" to the estimand while the CI is only supposed to cover the parameter it estimates with a minimal probability. (Weird but correct example: create a 95% CI by using a 99% CI and randomly--with a 4% chance--*changing* the endpoints of the 99% CI into an impossible range.)  This mis-match also happens with extreme cases (such as count data with zero counts), when approximations are used, and when the estimate is not made with the same assumptions as the CI.

Comment: It would be unusual for a *point estimate* not to be inside a 95% CI. Did you mean that the population parameter is not inside the CI? (If so, this is not necessarily saying anything.) If you really do mean the point estimate is not inside the CI, please give an example.

Comment: This is one of those cases where going to the original [source of the whole concept](http://www.med.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/hanley/tmp/proportion/wilson_jasa_1927.pdf) will help :)

Comment: It might be an error in the data generation process. I just saw this happen while constructing bootstrapped confidence intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that a 95% confidence interval will NOT contain the true parameter value 5% of the time if all of the assumptions are valid. Either your model is valid and you are experiencing the 5%, or your model is invalid and you need to check the assumptions.

Comment: The question is about the estimate, not the true parameter. But perhaps the question is not well phrased.